# CSS: How to change the color of the bottom right square of the scrollbar in webkit?

Tags: html, css, webkit

Question:

How can I change the color of the bottom-right square of the scrollbar (to black) in webkit (Google-Chrome) ?

[image: Scrollbar]

This is what I have so far:

```
/*
http://www.coffeepowered.net/2011/06/17/sexy-css-scrollbars/
http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/
*/
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px; }

::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
    height: 18px; }

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment 
{
    height: 15px;
    width: 13px;
    display: block;
    background: #101211;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement 
{
    background-image: url(./images/horizontal-decrement-arrow.png);
    background-position: 4px 3px; 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:increment 
{
    background-image: url(./images/horizontal-increment-arrow.png);
    background-position: 3px 3px; 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement 
{
    background-image: url(./images/vertical-decrement-arrow.png);
    background-position: 3px 4px; 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment 
{
    background-image: url(./images/vertical-increment-arrow.png);
    background-position: 3px 4px; 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement:active { background-image: url(./images/horizontal-decrement-arrow-active.png); }

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:increment:active { background-image: url(./images/horizontal-increment-arrow-active.png); }

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement:active { background-image: url(./images/vertical-decrement-arrow-active.png); }

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment:active { background-image: url(./images/vertical-increment-arrow-active.png); }


::-webkit-scrollbar-track 
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-color: #151716; }

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical 
{
    height: 50px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #4d4d4d), color-stop(100%, #333333));
    border: 1px solid #0d0d0d;
    border-top: 1px solid #666666;
    border-left: 1px solid #666666; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal 
{
    width: 50px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #4d4d4d), color-stop(100%, #333333));
    border: 1px solid #1f1f1f;
    border-top: 1px solid #666666;
    border-left: 1px solid #666666; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

Comment: I see a scrollbar to the left and one above but the square is not part of a scrollbar.

Comment: @stark: It is, but not of thumb. It is corner.

Comment: Isn't it just the frame background?

Comment: @stark: Nope, definitely not. The frame background is set to gray.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ah, never mind:

Answer found [here](http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/overflow-scrollbar-combinations.html)

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
/*
background-image: url(resources/corner.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
*/
background-color: #3D3D3D;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question. Did save me quite a bit of time.

Comment: @Jeremy Chone: Thanks for the confirmation, I suspected so ;)