# How to apply a style to the <HTML> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, scrollbar

Question: How do I apply this style via JavaScript ? 
jQuery also welcome :)

**Note:** 
It must be applied to the `<HTML>` element, not the `document.body` element.
Otherwise it doesn't work.

```
<style type="text/css">
html {
scrollbar-arrow-color: Orange;
scrollbar-base-color: Black;
scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: Black;
scrollbar-track-color: Gray;
scrollbar-face-color: Black;
scrollbar-shadow-color: Silver;
scrollbar-highlight-color: Silver;
scrollbar-3d-light-color: Silver;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Scrollbar colors? Haven't seen these properties in a *long* time.

Comment: You can use html as a selector - $("html")

Comment: You are aware that scrollbar properties only work in IE and (I think) Opera and are not valid CSS?

Comment: @ Rob: I know. See here for a webkit-version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667890/css-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-bottom-right-square-of-the-scrollbar-in-webk ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, actually it's dead simple:

```
$('html').attr('style', strStyle);
```

Full example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function SetScrollbarStyle() 
    {

        with (document.frmCustomize) 
        {
            var strStyle = 'scrollbar-arrow-color: ' + arrow.value + ';' + "\n" + 'scrollbar-base-color: ' + base.value + ";\n" + 'scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: ' + darkshadow.value + ";\n" + 'scrollbar-track-color: ' + track.value + ";\n" + 'scrollbar-face-color: ' + face.value + ";\n" + 'scrollbar-shadow-color: ' + shadow.value + ";\n" + 'scrollbar-highlight-color: ' + highlight.value + ";\n" + 'scrollbar-3d-light-color: ' + light.value + ";";
            code.value = '<style type="text/css">' + "\n" + 'html {' + "\n" + strStyle + "\n}" + "\n" + '</style>' + "\n";
            //$('body').css('background-color', '#ff0000');
            //$('body').css(strStyle);
            //$('body').attr('style', strStyle);
            $('html').attr('style', strStyle);
        }

    }
</script>
```

Where SetScrollbarStyle is called from a form-button onclick event.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `addClass` method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('html').addClass('aClass')
   // or $('html').css('property', 'value')
})
```

where *aClass* is the name of the class that should be added to `html` tag.

Comment: You're assuming I have such a class pre-defined. Probably my mistake, I should have said that I generate the style with JavaScript using a user-input form, so it's not pre-defined, it's customizable.

Comment: @Quandary Yes, in that case you can use `css` method.

Comment: I wanted set a complete style string (see my answer), not every element on it's own. But that undoubtedly works. If I hadn't to output the style-string, then it would be the better solution. Anyway, +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('html').css({
    "scrollbar-arrow-color":"Orange",
  });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('html').css({
    "scrollbar-arrow-color","Orange",
  });
});
```

or you may define your style in some some class and use the `addClass` method like;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('html').addClass('your_class');
});
```